# How to align Two TextViews next to each other in LinnearLayouts?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to put two TextViews next to each other but somehow I can't get it to work. I wanted to have the following: **txtViewAddress: txtAddress**
I've tried putting android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtViewAddress"
I also tried putting layout_toLeftOf, but both did not work.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CalendarID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtViewAddress"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_update"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delete"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why are you giving orientation vertical if you actully need it horizontal?

Comment: just change your LinearLayout to orientation _vertical_ TO  _horizontal_ which you have **Textviews of addreses**

Comment: I did put the orientation to horizontal but the first two textviews are fine. I have multiple textviews. 1st line is ADDRESS: Address from database, second line Check in Date: Checkin date from database, 3rd line Checkout date: Checkout date pulled from database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need views inside a linear layout next to each other, the orientation of your layout must be horizontal.

You can also use the constraint layout, it has much more flexibility in placing view on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtViewAddress"` is atrribute part of Relative Layout

**Use this code**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtViewAddress"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just show me an image or draw something  what exactly you want, so I can change my code based on that

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address: "
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtViewAddress"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

change the `android:orientation="vertical"` to `android:orientation="horizontal"`
and you can also use `android:weightSum="2"`  weightSum is used to define the priority of the view
if you give equal weight to all views inside linear layout then all the views take on equal amount of space inside the Linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

this should be like following

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

.....
......
.....
    </LinearLayout>
```

and also I  suggest that do not give fix width to layout instead you set it releted to screen size

Comment: The problem is that I have a multiple textviews and needs to be Vertical